# relation between two rotations

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I have two objects, each of them has its own rotational matrix relative to the same base. but i want to make one object as the base, and have the other objects rotation based on that.

what i did in opengl:

two rotational matrix R1 and R2;

what i did is (not actual code, but same math)

```
glPushMatrix();
glMultMatrix(R1^-1);
glMultMatrix(R2);
glPopMatrix();
```

but the output turns out with yaw and pitch switched and roll inversed

anyone knows what the problem is ?

Comment: Why are you doing `glmultmatrix(R1^-1)` instead of `glmultmatrix(R1)`?

Comment: OpenGL is not a math library. You should to this kind of thing using a real math library, for example GLM.

Comment: yeah i know, i did Rt = glm::inverse(R1) and use glmultmatrix(Rt), to be more clear, the code is like:

R1 and R2 are known and
Rt = glm::inverse(R1)  then do
glPushMatrix();
glMultMatrix(Rt);
glMultMatrix(R2);
glPopMatrix();

Comment: Try using r1*r2^-1, matrix multiplication is not commutative so remember to multiply in the correct order. Then you have child transformation r1*r2^-1*r2=r1 which is the matrix you are looking for